# Building a tree with multiple roots from database in primefaces

Tags: mongodb, jsf, jakarta-ee, primefaces, tree

I'm working with primefaces tree. I'm facing problems with constructing tree which has multiple roots. I'm new in MongoDB and primefaces tree. Lots of people have mind blowing brain. So please help. I would really appreciate your effort. Below is my code with demo data.

```
Data:
**nodeid      nodeTitle     parentId    parentTitle** 
   00                        0
   000                       00
   001                       00
   001.01                    001
   01                        0
   010                       01
   10                        1
   100                       10
```

//Node Class

```
public class Node {
    private String nodeid;
    private String nodeTitle;

    Parent parent;

    public String getNodeId() {
        return nodeid;
    }
    public void setNodeId(String nodeid) {
        this.nodeid = nodeid;
    }
    public Parent getParent() {
        return parent;
    }
    public void setParent(Parent parent) {
        this.parent = parent;
    }

    public String getNodeTitle() {
        return nodeTitle;
    }
    public void setNodeTitle(String nodeTitle) {
        this.nodeTitle = nodeTitle;
    }
}
```

//Main managed bean class

```
import org.primefaces.model.DefaultTreeNode;
import org.primefaces.model.TreeNode;

@ManagedBean(name = "nodeHierarchy")
@SessionScoped
public class NodeHierarchy implements Serializable{
    private TreeNode rootNode;
    private static DB db;
    @SuppressWarnings("unused")
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    List<Node> nodeList = new ArrayList<Node>();

    public TreeNode getRootNode() {
        return rootNode;
    }

    public void setRootNode(TreeNode node) {
        this.rootNode = node;
    }

    @SuppressWarnings({ "unchecked" })
    public List<Node>NodeData() throws UnknownHostException{
        List<Node> nodeList = new ArrayList<Node>();
        DBConnection dbRecords = DBConnection.getInstance();
        db = dbRecords.getNodedb();
        DBCollection collection = db.getCollection("nodeRelation");
        BasicDBObject treeQuery = new BasicDBObject();
        treeQuery.put("nodeid", new BasicDBObject("$gte","0"));
        DBCursor cursor = collection.find(treeQuery);

        while (cursor.hasNext()) {
            Node node = new Node();
            Parent parent = new Parent();
            DBObject DBobj = cursor.next();


     //ID/NodeID:       
            DBObject nodeObject = (BasicDBObject) DBobj.get("nodeid");
            node.setNodeId((String)nodeObject);
            DBObject nodeTitleDe = (BasicDBObject) DBobj.get("nodeTitle");
            node.setNodeTitle((String) nodeTitleDe.get("de"));

   //Parent/Root:       
            DBObject parentNode = (BasicDBObject) DBobj.get("parentId");
            parent.setParentId(parentNode.toString());
            DBObject parentTitleDe = (BasicDBObject) parentNode.get("parentTitle");
            parent.setParentTitle((String) parentTitleDe.get("de"));
            node.setParent(parent); 

            nodeList.add(node);
       }

       return nodeList;
   }

   public TreeNode createDocuments() throws UnknownHostException {
       TreeNode rootNode = new DefaultTreeNode("Root Node", null);
       List<Node> documentRootNodeList = NodeData();
       for (Node doc : documentRootNodeList) {
           TreeNode node = createSubNode(doc.getParent().getParentId(), rootNode);
       }
       return rootNode;
   }

   public TreeNode createSubNode(String doc, TreeNode node) throws UnknownHostException {
        TreeNode newNode = new DefaultTreeNode(doc, node);
        List<Node> documentList = NodeData();
        for (Node subDoc : documentList) {
            TreeNode subNode = createSubNode(subDoc.getNotation(), newNode);
        }
        return newNode;
    }
```

nodeid is the list of all nodes and parentId is the root. But the tree has multiple roots like: 0, 1. And it will generate full tree.

nodeHierarchy.xhtml

```
 <h:form id="nodeDataForm">
      <p:tree id="nodeTree" var="node" value="#{nodeHierarchy.rootNode}" >
          <p:treeNode>
              <h:outputText value="#{node.nodeid} #{node.nodeTitle}" dynamic="true" />
          </p:treeNode> 
      </p:tree>
 </h:form>
```

Comment: What does it mean multiple root ( does it mean ellement with parent null ) ?!?

Comment: Thank you for asking. The root will be like this 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9. And each root has their child and may be some of the child has their own child. For example: 0--00, 0--01, 0--02; 00--000, 00--001; 001--001.01 so on. Same as for the other roots. Each tree series will start from its roots in common. Please if you have a solution help me.